# understanding couchbase server

Tags: couchbase, couchbase-lite, couchbase-sync-gateway

[image]

We are developing an App which has overall core 15 modules. Whenever a new business is registered either thru mobile or thru web, then we planned to create 15 docs (biz1_users, biz1_loans..etc) which are array type like below. (ref fig 1.0) ex : User Module

Note : There is possibility that a user can have two different business of same type but mobile app has to handle both the biz. Ex : Biz3 and Biz4

User Module : user.json(shema)

```
{
userProfile :[
{Name : user1, Phone : xxxxxxx },
{Name : user2, Phone : xxxx },.....
        ] 
}
    Fig 1.0
```

Is the above approach valid/optimal way. If not what is the best approach?

Couchbase Lite :
How to update a single user using couchbase lite when User object which is an array?
How to verify user registration process from mobile, whether is user already exist or not? 
How to sync particular user's(profile updates) as per the above (fig 1.0) to the server?
How to establish file uploading from mobile during offline and online?
How to handle backup and restore using couchbase lite?
How to handle sync up of single user details updated both web & mobile at single instance?

Comment: You're asking too many questions packed into one post here.  Some of these questions are standard and explained in the basic documentation.  Please spend some time researching answers and post individual specific questions.  See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.